# HttpCallout.InvalidNamedCredentialException: Named Credential: xxx not configured in Salesforce

Tags: namedcredentials

I'm testing an Apex callout using Named Credentials and getting this error

```
HttpCallout.InvalidNamedCredentialException: 
Named Credential: hipaaorder_staging not configured in Salesforce
```

But the NamedCredential exists in my org.

How do I diagnose/fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is pretty simple

Named Credentials are *case sensitive*.

```
Org Named Credential configured as hipaaOrder_staging 
But the code was looking for       hipaaorder_staging
```